# Structure [object] c language

Tags: c++

Output:

a) list of items

b) a list of objects in a given year of study

c) list of objects in a given faculty

d) list of objects in a given cathedra

e) maximum number of hours

To realize functions that provide menu operations..

Structure of the OBJECT with fields: name, year, faculty, cathedra, number of hours.

I am getting errors:

```
89  [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char [1]' to 'char [4]'

91  [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

92  [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct object{
    char title[1];
    int year,kol;
    char faculty[2];
    char cathedra[3];
} t1;
void input(FILE *);
void print(FILE *);
void app(FILE *);
void desh(FILE *); 

main(){
    char c;
    FILE *tf;
    while (1){
        puts(" 1  Input data");
        puts(" 2  Output the number of hours");
        puts(" 3  Exit");
        c=getch();
        switch(c)
        {
        case '1': input(tf); break;
        case '2': desh(tf); break;
        case '3': return 0;
        default : puts(" Wrong mode");
        }
    }
}
void input(FILE *tf)
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n Input data\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: "); scanf("%s",t1.title);
        printf("\n Year of study: "); scanf("%f",t1.year);
        printf("\n Name of the faculty: "); scanf("%s",&t1.faculty);
        printf("\n Name of the cathedra: "); scanf("%s",&t1.cathedra);
        printf("\n Number of hours: "); scanf("%d",&t1.kol);
        fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        printf("\n Finish input? y/n ");
        ch=getch();
    }
    while (ch != 'y');
    fclose(tf);
}

void print(FILE *tf){
    int i;
    i=1;
    fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
    while (!feof(tf))
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: %s, Year of study: %f, Name of the faculty: %s, Name of the cathedra: %s, Number of hours:%d", i,t1.title,t1.year,t1.faculty,t1.cathedra,t1.kol);
        fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        i++;
    }
}

void app(FILE *tf)
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n Input data\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: "); scanf("%s",t1.title);
        printf("\n Year of study : "); scanf("%f",t1.year);
        printf(" Name of the faculty: "); scanf("%s",&t1.faculty);
        printf(" Name of the cathedra : "); scanf("%s",&t1.cathedra);
        printf(" Number of hours : "); scanf("%d",&t1.kol);
        fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        printf(" Finish input? y/n ");
        ch=getch();}
    while (ch != 'y');
    fclose(tf);
}
void desh(FILE *tf){
    char a[4];
    float max=500, s;
    int i,b,c,d;
    fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
    while (!feof(tf)){
        if(t1.kol>max){
            max=t1.kol;
            a=t1.title; // line 89
            b=t1.year;
            c=t1.faculty; // line 91
            d=t1.cathedra; // line 92
            s=t1.kol;
        }
    }

    printf("Max number of hours:\n");
    printf("\n The name of the object: %s Year of study: %f Name of the faculty: %s Name of the cathedra: %s,Number of hours : %d",a,b,c,d,s);
    fclose(tf);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212704/discussion-on-question-by-tochka-zapitaia-structure-object-c-language).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make the strings in the structure large enough to hold the inputs. I use 30 below.
2. You have to use `%d` to input and output the year, not `%f`, because it's an `int`.
3. You must use `&` before the an integer variable in `scanf()`, you shouldn't use it with a string.
4. The variables `a`, `c`, and `d` need to be declared as `char` arrays so you can copy the strings from the struct to them.
5. You must use `strcpy()` to copy strings, not assignment.
6. Don't use `while (!feof(tf))` to loop through the input. Use `while (fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf))`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define STRSIZE 30

struct object{
    char title[STRSIZE];
    int year,kol;
    char faculty[STRSIZE];
    char cathedra[STRSIZE];
} t1;
void input(FILE *);
void print(FILE *);
void app(FILE *);
void desh(FILE *); 

main(){
    char c;
    FILE *tf;
    while (1){
        puts(" 1  Input data");
        puts(" 2  Output the number of hours");
        puts(" 3  Exit");
        c=getch();
        switch(c)
        {
        case '1': input(tf); break;
        case '2': desh(tf); break;
        case '3': return 0;
        default : puts(" Wrong mode");
        }
    }
}
void input(FILE *tf)
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n Input data\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: "); scanf("%s",t1.title);
        printf("\n Year of study: "); scanf("%d",&t1.year);
        printf("\n Name of the faculty: "); scanf("%s",t1.faculty);
        printf("\n Name of the cathedra: "); scanf("%s",t1.cathedra);
        printf("\n Number of hours: "); scanf("%d",&t1.kol);
        fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        printf("\n Finish input? y/n ");
        ch=getch();
    }
    while (ch != 'y');
    fclose(tf);
}

void print(FILE *tf){
    int i;
    i=1;
    ;
    while (fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf))
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: %s, Year of study: %d, Name of the faculty: %s, Name of the cathedra: %s, Number of hours:%d", i,t1.title,t1.year,t1.faculty,t1.cathedra,t1.kol);
        fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        i++;
    }
}

void app(FILE *tf)
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n Input data\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n The name of the object: "); scanf("%s",t1.title);
        printf("\n Year of study : "); scanf("%f",t1.year);
        printf(" Name of the faculty: "); scanf("%s",&t1.faculty);
        printf(" Name of the cathedra : "); scanf("%s",&t1.cathedra);
        printf(" Number of hours : "); scanf("%d",&t1.kol);
        fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);
        printf(" Finish input? y/n ");
        ch=getch();}
    while (ch != 'y');
    fclose(tf);
}
void desh(FILE *tf){
    char a[STRSIZE];
    int max=500, s;
    char c[STRSIZE];
    char d[STRSIZE];

    while (fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf)){
        if(t1.kol>max){
            max=t1.kol;
            strcpy(a, t1.title);
            b=t1.year;
            strcpy(c, t1.faculty);
            strcpy(d, t1.cathedra);
            s=t1.kol;
        }
    }

    printf("Max number of hours:\n");
    printf("\n The name of the object: %s Year of study: %d Name of the faculty: %s Name of the cathedra: %s,Number of hours : %d",a,b,c,d,s);
    fclose(tf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, program runs but i still can't print name of faculty and get max number of hours.

Comment: Is the max hours more than `500`?

Comment: You never call `fopen()`. What file is `tf` supposed to read and write?

Comment: i am not use print from a file, i just type from myself

Comment: You never open a file. Where is it supposed to be reading from?

Comment: I type on my keyboard total data

Comment: You type it yourself and then save it into a file with `fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf);`. Then the loop that finds the maximum uses `fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,tf)` to read from the file.

Comment: But you never open a file, so where is this supposed to be writing and reading?

Comment: How to realize opening from file "txt"?

Comment: Read about `fopen()`